# Merging Google sheets based on a common column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a Google Apps Script to merge data in two sheets based on one common column (email) in Google Sheets. Example:

```
Sheet 1
Name Email       Address  
A    a@abc.com    abc
B    b@dgh.com    ghc
C    f@abc.com    sdf

Sheet 2
Email       Quantity   Size
b@dgh.com   3          5
```

I'm looking for (emails in sheet 2 are a subset of emails in sheet 1):

```
Sheet 3 (or new spreadsheet)

Email       Name    Address  Quantity Size
b@dgh.com   B       ghc      3          5
```

I've looked into VLOOKUP but I couldn't figure out how to use it to merge 2 sheets very large in size.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? It's unclear how you expect this to work.

Comment: Create sheet 3 by copying sheet 2. Then use a VLookup to get the name, and another VLookup to get the address.

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes the resulting sheet 3 is a subset of sheet 1 based on email in both sheet 1 and 2. A variation is possible for other assumptions.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA ({Sheet2!A2:A3,VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2:A3,{Sheet1!B2:C,Sheet1!A2:A},{3,2},0),Sheet2!B2:B3, Sheet2!C2:C3})
```

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) places the 2+ arrays, the original and the result from the VLOOKUP, into a new location where the formula is entered. If the arrays are not the same size (row count in resulting tables) it will throw a #REF error. Due to the custom column order, this example has 4 arrays created from the two tables. If the column order is arbitrary, it is possible to avoid ARRAYFORMULA and use VLOOKUP in sheet 2 to pull the columns from sheet 1 next to the other columns.

[VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) grabs the partial table's single column to join on and grabs the rest of the columns from the full list that match exactly. The resulting columns are numeric since the resulting table may not have the same [column numbers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=en) (C, B in the range provided).